# How do I initialize a list<> with two dimensional arrays?

Tags: c#, arraylist

```
List<int[,]> table = new List<int[,]> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

This isn't right, but I'm stumped on how to do it.
Basically in the end I want to say table[0] and get back the first tuple, table[2] and get back the second tuple, and so on.

What is the correct format (if I have the right data model) or the correct data structure for what I want to do?

I have a pretty hefty list of tuples in the above format, And I like to stay with the format if at all possible.

Comment: You have a collection of muti dimensional arrays, the collection initializer you have used is for a single multi dimensional array. in short you would need another dimension

Comment: The correct syntax is: `List<int[,]> table = new List<int[,]> { new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };` but I wouldn't recommend that. For readability, I'd create the array(s) first: `int[,] arr1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };` and then initialize the list: `var table = new List<int[,]> { arr1 };`. Note that in both cases, that's just one array (which is probably not what you intended). You seem to be confusing `int[]` arrays with `int[,]` arrays somehow.

Comment: Doing this doesn't let me index anything beyond table[0]. And table[0] includes the entire collection (hundreds of tuples.)
What I want to say is table[0] and get back only the first tuple, etc.

Comment: Well, what you're referring to as "the first tuple" (assuming you mean `{1, 2}`) is a single-dimension array. Did you want a `List<int[]>` instead? Or perhaps a `List<(int, int)>`?

Comment: I think so, yes .. but the compiler complains if I try to init this way:
List<int[]> table = new List<int[]> { new int[] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };

Comment: Yeah, in that case, you'd need `new List<int[]> { new int[] { 1, 2 }, ... }`. That said, since you keep mentioning tuples, you're probably better off using actual (value-)tuples: `var table = new List<(int, int)> { ( 1, 2 ), ( 3, 4 ), ( 5, 6 ), ( 7, 8 ) };` - Does that work for you?

Comment: I get the error: Error CS8179 Predefined type 'System.ValueTuple`2' is not defined or imported. Do I need some sort of reference?

Comment: What .net are you using, and why is it so old ?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4. Is that insufficient?

Comment: .net 4 was released in 2010, and ended its life 5 years ago, there is no reason you should be using it

Comment: Alright, I'll upgrade to 5. We'll see how it goes. ty for all the help!

Comment: @Level42 Note that .NET 5 is _not_ .NET Framework; it's a subsequent to .NET Core. There are some [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) that you should be aware of when migrating from .NET Framework to .NET Core or .NET 5. If you're looking for an easy upgrade, consider using .NET Framework 4.8 or 4.72.

Comment: I tried to upgrade my project to .NET 5, and it looks to be a bit more work than had planned. I went with the simpler  int[,] a = new int[4, 2] {{ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 }}; which seems to do the trick. It's a couple of lines of code to suck the tuple out, but it works and is probably reasonably efficient.

Comment: *I tried to upgrade my project to .NET 5* - .net 5 is not exactly the follow on to .net 4; .net 4.8 the most modern version of framework. *suck the tuple out* - It's not a tuple in a c# sense; you should cease calling it that as you'll only cause confusion